# Linq: method cannot be translated into a store expression

Tags: c#, .net, linq, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-entities

I am currently trying to limit which users can access which groups, and am doing this by using linq.  My problem occours when I am adding the relevant groups to the view.

The error I keep getting is:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   GetUserId(System.Security.Principal.IIdentity)' method, and this
>   method cannot be translated into a store expression

This is my code:

```
  var groupUser = db.GroupUsers.Where(u => u.ApplicationUserId == User.Identity.GetUserId()).Select(gr => gr.GroupId);
  pv.GroupList = db.Groups.Where(g => groupUser.Contains(g.Id)).ToList();
  return View(pv);
```

Comment: Extract `User.Identity.GetUserId()` into a variable.

Comment: This helped! Thanks!

Comment: **@YacoubMassad** - Post it as an answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to call `GetUserId()` outside the lambda expression, as Linq to Entities is not able to translate it to corresponding SQL (of course there is no SQL alternative for `GetUserId()`):

```
var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
var groupUser = db.GroupUsers.Where(u => u.ApplicationUserId == userId)
                             .Select(gr => gr.GroupId);
```