# ASP.net MVC: Display Results For A Specific User

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP.net MVC with Individual User Accounts. I want a page that shows all database records where the field "user" equals the email address of the account. I used scaffolding to create everything, I just need to add a where clause somehow that only shows records for the specific user. I attempted that in the controller below. It compiles, and Exhibit5/Index/ prompts user with login screen as expected. However, upon clicking LogIn, I get a network path not found error.

Model:

```
public partial class Exhibit5
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string ProposedTitle { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> AnnualizedSalary { get; set; }
    public string PayGrade { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> MktPay { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> RangeMin { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> RangeMid { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> RangeMax { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> RangePen { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> CompaRatio { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> BelowMin { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> AboveMax { get; set; }
}
```

}

Controller:

```
public class Exhibit5Controller : Controller
    {
        private WebApplication1Context db = new WebApplication1Context();
        [Authorize]
        // GET: Exhibit5
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var ex5 = db.Exhibit5.Where(d => d.User == User.Identity.GetUserName()).ToList();
            return View(ex5);
        }
```

Comment: Did you debug the code? Does it go to the post action of login? Does username and password validation happens properly?

Comment: ^ That. Also, is `Identity` actually set for this request? Also, are you sure you created a View for this action?

Comment: In debugging, I am getting the following error now: System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String GetUserId(System.Security.Principal.IIdentity)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'

Comment: I figured it out using this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37435109/linq-method-cannot-be-translated-into-a-store-expression Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
var userName = User.Identity.GetUserName();
var ex5 = db.Exhibit5.Where(u => u.User == userName )
                         .Select(y => y.User);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Quick-fix:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   var userName = User.Identity.GetUserName();
   var ex5 = db.Exhibit5.Where(d => d.User == userName).ToList();
   return View(ex5);
}
```

The reason `User.Identity.GetUserName()` doesn't work inside `Where` because *Entity Framework* needs to convert your `Where` code into SQL Queries and it doesn't know how to do `User.Identity.GetUserName()`. By pulling it out of makes *Entity Framework do* (kind of) this:

```
SELECT * FROM Exhibit5 WHERE User = <User Name>
```